# Turn off WordPress new comment notifications for one specific user (not admin)

Tags: wordpress, comments

A user made a comment on a popular post and checked the 'notify on future comments' button. She now wants to turn those off or be removed from that.

How can I turn off WordPress new comment notifications for one specific user for one specific comment thread?